# google cloud storage.object.delete permission for bucket deleted, want to reaccess

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

message when i want to delete the bucket

**Bucket cannot be deleted**

The selected bucket cannot be deleted because you're missing the storage.objects.delete permission for this bucket.

Ask the bucket administrator to grant you this permission, then try again.

how can i regain the access and delete the bucket.

Comment: The message says "Ask the bucket administrator to grant you this permission". Who is the administrator?

Answer (score 0):

If you are project owner, you could go to the IAM & admin dashboard and add the "Storage Admin" role to your account, with this action you should be able to get access to the bucket and delete it. You can also use the following command on Cloud Shell to get the same result:

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT_ID] --member=user:[YOUR_EMAIL] --role=roles/storage.admin

Comment: tried but unable to find the "Storage Amin" role option

Comment: If you want to do this by using the Cloud Console, please follow this steps:

1. Go to the link https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/projects
2. Select your project.
3. Select the edit button on the left of your account.
4. Select the option "Add another role".
5. Type "Storage Admin" in the filter.
6. Save changes.

Answer (score 0):

open the console and go to https://console.cloud.google.com/storage

click edit bucket option

and change the IAM policy and latter you can use and delete the bucket too